# Scope in events in web3 1.0

Tags: web3js, truffle, truffle-contract, web3js-v1.x

Inside the callback of an event, how do I get the scope outside the function? Specifically, in the following scenario, I want the web3 object:
(using truffle-contracts and web3 1.0 here)

```
...
const web3 = new Web3(someProvider);

myContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    // both ways work
    instance.myEvent({}, function(error, event) {
        // here, I want to use web3
        web3.toAscii(event.args[0])
    })
});
```

Comment: Take a look at general javascript scope rules https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a variable in Javascript without `const` or `var` clause, it will be defined globally.
So you can write:

```
web3 = new Web3(someProvider);
```

For more information about variables scope in Javascript see:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp